# How to count the occurrences of a string value row wise in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where i have a table containing some values where i have three columns which contains three names in every row ,now what my requirement is that, i have to count that occurrences of names in that table & repetition of occurrences will be treated as 1.And i have to show the occurrences in a  column  in comma(,) separated format like if occurrences is two then have to show like 1,1.This is my table structure and also i am posting what  format i want ,

This is the table i have,

```
id  name1  name2 name3 
 1   A       A     B
 2   B       C     D
 3   A       A     A
```

Now what my requirement is that

```
 id name1 name2 name3  count 
 1   A       A     B   1,1
 2   B       C     D   1,1,1
 3   A       A     A   1
```

How to achieve this ,somebody please help

Comment: What happens if the data is `A, B, A`?

Comment: @Bohemian Then it will be 1,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case`:

```
select id, name1, name2, name3,
  case
    when name1 = name2 and name2 = name3 then '1'
    when name1 != name2 and name1 != name3 and name2 != name3 then '1,1,1'
    else '1,1' end count
from mytable
```

Note how the testing of cases when all same and all different first mean the else covers all other combinations that can result in `1,1`.

---

If you just want the number of different values (as a numeric value - as per your comments):

```
select id, name1, name2, name3,
  case
    when name1 = name2 and name2 = name3 then 1
    when name1 != name2 and name1 != name3 and name2 != name3 then 3
    else 2 end count
from mytable
```

Comment: thanks a lot but i wanted the numbers as integer coz in my application i have to multiply an amount on the basis of count .i.e if 1,1 then i have to multiply $20 as 2 * $20 that way.is that achiveble??

Comment: I don't understand - "1,1" can only be text. Mysql doesn't have an srray type. What datatype were you hoping for?

Comment: my purpose is to multiply an amount with the count of the comma separated values i.e if 1,1 then 2* $20 ,if 1 then 1*$20 ,if 1,1,1 then 3*$20 that way

Comment: @lucifer why not just return the number 1, 2 or 3 then? Why the comma delimited list of ones?

Comment: no comma delimited output is needed  i can show the total count in another  column ,can you help ??

Comment: returning only the count will be also ok like 1,2 or 3 as you suggested